# sync two local MS SQL Servers over wifi using a network drive

Tags: sql-server

I have a Windows application that stores its data on a local MS SQL Server database, on the same machine.
I use this application at home in two different computers, which are connected to the same local wifi network.
I never use these two computers at the same time.

I would like to have these 2 databases synchronized, using a network hard drive, which is connected to my wifi wouter (like a NAS). Beware it's just a network hard disk, not a full NAS with services running on it.

Can you tell me if MS SQL Server offers any sync option for this use case?
Any alternatives are also welcome.

I can also replace the network drive with a cloud provider (like Onedrive) but it should work as above.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.
Here is a representation of the use case:

Main PC (App + MS SQL Server)

||

Wifi network  <==>  Nas HDD

||

Secondary PC (App + MS SQL Server)

Comment: Anyway, "synchronization" isn't magic: you still need to **think and plan** about how you'll actually perform that synchronization - and you'll be short of options if your tables don't have _useful things_ like `PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME`, a `rowversion` column, `rowguid` columns - and even then you need to think about how you'll deal with conflict resolution. Basically, this is a _huge_ area of active study everywhere, and it isn't as simple as you think it is...

Comment: If you install and configure a server instance that is always running, then any of your apps running on any machine can always access the instance and use the database - no "sync" required.

Comment: @Dai You seem to know what you are talking about. Good for you.
But the tone your first reply is very unfriendly: starting with "oooooh boy".. This is a lack of respect for me and the Stackoverflow community.
Your second reply shows that you did not center the point of the question, which is requesting some already existent solution that could just work in this case. E.g. tools, scripts..  
Abstain from posting a list of technical terms just to show how good you are. We can already find books about this field. The db structure cannot be modified, and as already said no risk of conflicts.